# Get features after autoencoder to use it in ANN model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoder

I need to create a model to combine 2 phases. first autoencoder to reconstruction features,  second using this reconstruction features in ANN to classify.

The problems:

1. How to get features from autoencoder? I using "predict" command but I get features with a repeated values as seeing here [Original features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC9xe.png) [predict features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTwEQ.png)?
2. How to get the top 100 features (data is high dimensional)?

her is the code of Autoencoder:

```py
# encoder
n_inputs =X.shape[1]
print("Print"+ str(n_inputs))
encoder_input = Input(shape=(X.shape[1],))
#encoder Level 1
en = Dense(n_inputs, activation = 'sigmoid')(encoder_input)
en = BatchNormalization()(en)
en = Dropout(0.3)(en)
#encoder Level 2
en = Dense(n_inputs/2, activation = 'relu')(en)
en = BatchNormalization()(en)
en = Dropout(0.3)(en)
#bottleneck
bottleneck = Dense(n_inputs/4)(en)
encodermodel=Model(encoder_input, bottleneck, name="Encoder")
# decoder level 1
de = Dense(n_inputs/2, activation = 'relu')(bottleneck)
de = BatchNormalization()(de)
de = Dropout(0.3)(de)
# decoder level 2
de = Dense(n_inputs, activation = 'relu')(de)
de= BatchNormalization()(de)
de = Dropout(0.3)(de)
#Output layer
decoded = Dense(n_inputs, activation = 'sigmoid')(de)



autoencoder = Model(encoder_input, decoded, name = 'Autoencoder_Model')
autoencoder.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam')
history = autoencoder.fit(X, X, epochs=20, batch_size=16,verbose=2 , validation_split=0.10) 
# define an encoder model (without the decoder)
# save the encoder to file
encodermodel.save("....../encoder.h5")

# load the model from file
autoencoderw = load_model('....../encoder.h5')
reduced_df = pd.DataFrame(autoencoderw.predict(X))
reduced_df = reduced_df.add_prefix('feature_')
print(reduced_df.head(-1))
```